# Simple problem svg `<image>` problem: repeating and not filling the space

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm trying to have the image fill the bounds of the `lime` box.
It works when `zoom === 1, positionDelta === [0,0]`:

[image: zoom === 1]

But behaving in a way that I don't expect when `zoom === 0.688, positionDelta === [0,19]`:

[image]

It **should** look like this (aside from the green stroke):
[image]

```
import computeFilters from './computeFilters';
import { useState } from 'react';

import imageMap from './imageMap';

export default function SvgImage({state,value,bounds,div, imageUrlMap}){

  const [dataUrl, setDataUrl] = useState(null);
  
  let {width, height, x, y} = bounds;

  let cropId = value.value.cropId;
  let crop = state.cropsById[ cropId ];
  let imageId = crop.imageId || state.imageSets[crop.imageSetId].figureImageId;
  let imageSet = state.imageSets[ crop.imageSetId ];
  let angle = imageSet.rotation;
  let imageRecord = state.imageUploadsById[ imageId ];
  let url = imageRecord.url;
  let adjustments = imageRecord.adjustments;
  let imgStyle = {height:crop.height * width, width, }
  let clipId = 'clip-'+div.id;

  console.log(value);

  let href = imageUrlMap[value._id]

  let zoom = (value.imageAdjustments && value.imageAdjustments.zoom) || 1;
  let [deltaX,deltaY] = (
    value.imageAdjustments && value.imageAdjustments.positionDelta
  ) || [0,0];

  let imageX = x + deltaX;
  let imageY = y + deltaY;
  let imageWidth = width * zoom;
  let imageHeight = height * zoom;


console.log(JSON.stringify({imageX,imageY,imageWidth,imageHeight,zoom,deltaX,deltaY}))

  return(
    <>

      <rect stroke="red" strokeWidth={1} x={x} y={y} width={width} height={height} fill={"none"}/>


      <rect stroke="lime" strokeWidth={3} 
      x={imageX} y={imageY} 
      width={imageWidth} height={imageHeight} fill={"none"}/>


      <image
        xlinkHref={href}
        width={imageWidth}
        height={imageHeight}
        x={imageX}
        y={imageY}
        preserveAspectRatio="none"

      /> 
    </>
  )
}
```

And if I set the following:

```
        xlinkHref={href}
        width={width}
        height={height}
        x={imageX}
        y={imageY}
        preserveAspectRatio="none"

      />
```

I get this:

[image]

I can try to clip it, but I don't understand why it won't just scale the way I tell it to and it feels the need to rudely insert more than I'm asking for into the view **uninvited**.

The console log for the three images are:

`{"imageX":52,"imageY":95,"imageWidth":309.59999999999997,"imageHeight":87.37599999999999,"zoom":0.688,"deltaX":0,"deltaY":19}`

`{"imageX":52,"imageY":203,"imageWidth":450,"imageHeight":38,"zoom":1,"deltaX":0,"deltaY":0}`

`{"imageX":52,"imageY":241,"imageWidth":450,"imageHeight":51,"zoom":1,"deltaX":0,"deltaY":0}`

Comment: You'd be a lot more likely to get an answer to this question if you created a minimal reproducible example of the question you are asking, instead of asking it in the literal context it is being experienced. As it stands, it is kind of hard to decipher.

Comment: Okay I'll do that